# How can you sort an array without mutating the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Let's suppose I wanted a sort function that returns a sorted copy of the inputted array. I naively tried this

```
function sort(arr) {
  return arr.sort();
}
```

and I tested it with this, which shows that my `sort` method is mutating the array.

```
var a = [2,3,7,5,3,7,1,3,4];
sort(a);
alert(a);  //alerts "1,2,3,3,3,4,5,7,7"
```

I also tried this approach

```
function sort(arr) {
  return Array.prototype.sort(arr);
}
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Is there a straightforward way around this, preferably a way that doesn't require hand-rolling my own sorting algorithm or copying every element of the array into a new one?

Comment: create a deep copy of the array and sort it instead.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal A shallow copy might be good enough if all is wanted is a reordering and not a duplicate of every item in the array.

Comment: `.sort` requires the `this` value to be the array, so for the last snippet to work you would do `.sort.call(arr)` (though it doesn't solve your problem).

Comment: @Kekoa Yeah that's a good point. There is no need to consume more memory if you're only going to change the order of the elements and not the elements themselves.

Comment: zzzzBov's method is working like a charm! https://stackoverflow.com/a/9592774/7011860

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### ES2023 Array Method [toSorted()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted):

> The **`toSorted()`** method of [`Array`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instances is the [copying](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#copying_methods_and_mutating_methods) version of the [`sort()`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method. It returns a new array with the elements sorted in ascending order.

```js
const arr = [2, 1, 3];
const arrSorted = arr.toSorted();
console.log(arr); //[2, 1, 3]
console.log(arrSorted); //[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 512):

You need to copy the array before you sort it. One way with es6:

```
const sorted = [...arr].sort();
```

The spread-syntax as array literal (copied from mdn):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [...arr]; // like arr.slice()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: this is really great.i think easier to understand than the concat and other approaches

Comment: this code does work, but when I compile the JS with Gulp it comes back with an error, SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (.)

Comment: To those saying it's not valid JavaScript... it's perfectly valid.  If you're in Chrome/Safari/Edge or Firefox: open the dev console, define an array called `arr` and paste the expression to see the result.

Comment: @Cerin It sounds like you are on an incredibly outdated version of JS.

Comment: Is this method faster than `.slice()` to get a copy of the array?

Comment: For more complex structures shallow cloning might be not enough, and something like this might be useful: `let arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));`

Comment: @NiKO for sorting, it's ok to have the original object. If you mutate the object afterwards, then you might have issues

Answer (score 258):

Just copy the array. There are many ways to do that:

```
function sort(arr) {
  return arr.concat().sort();
}

// Or:
return Array.prototype.slice.call(arr).sort(); // For array-like objects
```

Comment: Will this do a deep copy, i.e., will nested objects and arrays also be copied?

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `concat` over say `slice(0)` or are they all pretty much just the same?

Comment: @JaredPar The result is equal. If you're really after micro-performance, you can set up (or look up) a perf check at http://jsperf.com/

Comment: @RobW not really interested in the micro perf. All of the samples I'd seen before use `slice` and I wanted to see if there was some inherent reason to prefer `concat`

Comment: @PeterOlson No, it's a shallow copy. If you really want a deep copy, use the search feature on Stack Overflow to find existing excellent answers for that.

Comment: @JaredPar JsPerf created. For my browse  at least, concat was marginally faster. Link: http://jsperf.com/array-shallow-copying

Comment: slice is a bit faster for me (about 5% on firefox 45 and chrome 54 on linux).

Comment: Slice is now reported as notably faster

Comment: @PeterOlson and be *sure* to choose a solution which is in an npm package. Don't copy-paste some code.

Comment: As proposed a few answers below, you can also use `Array.from` which I find a little bit more expressive: `Array.from(arr).sort()`
With `slice` and `concat`, I find the array duplication intension is less evident.

Comment: why `Array.prototype.slice.call(arr).sort();` instead of `arr.slice().sort();` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé The prototype call works for array-like objects, too. Not only arrays themselves.

Answer (score 81):

Try the following

```
function sortCopy(arr) { 
  return arr.slice(0).sort();
}
```

The `slice(0)` expression creates a copy of the array starting at element 0.

Answer (score 56):

You can use slice with no arguments to copy an array:

```
var foo,
    bar;
foo = [3,1,2];
bar = foo.slice().sort();
```

Answer (score 21):

You can also do this

```
d = [20, 30, 10]
e = Array.from(d)
e.sort()
```

This way d will not get mutated.

```
function sorted(arr) {
  temp = Array.from(arr)
  return temp.sort()
}

//Use it like this
x = [20, 10, 100]
console.log(sorted(x))
```

Answer (score 16):

**Update - `Array.prototype.toSorted()` proposal**

The `Array.prototype.toSorted(compareFn) -> Array` is a new method that was proposed to be added to the `Array.prototype` and is currently in [stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-change-array-by-copy) (Soon to be available).

This method will keep the target Array untouched and return a copy with the change performed instead.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who wants to do a deep copy (e.g. if your array contains objects) can use:

```
let arrCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Then you can sort `arrCopy` without changing `arr`.

```
arrCopy.sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.id > obj2.id)
```

***Please note: this can be slow for very large arrays.***

Comment: This will work with `-` instead of `>` in your second example.

Comment: and remember all your items should be serializable in order to bring them back after stringifying ( eg. date objects, functions and symbols are problematic in this method )

Answer (score 2):

There's a new [tc39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-change-array-by-copy), which adds a `toSorted` method to `Array` that returns a copy of the array and doesn't modify the original.

For example:

```js
const sequence = [3, 2, 1];
sequence.toSorted(); // => [1, 2, 3]
sequence; // => [3, 2, 1]
```

As it's currently in stage 3, it will likely be implemented in browser engines soon, but in the meantime a polyfill is available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.tosorted) or in [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#change-array-by-copy).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that if no argument is passed to `sort`, it will not properly sort numbers by value. For numbers, try this. This does not mutate the original array.

```
function sort(arr) {
  return arr.slice(0).sort((a,b) => a-b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also extend the existing Array functionality. This allows chaining different array functions together.

```js
Array.prototype.sorted = function (compareFn) {
    const shallowCopy = this.slice();
    shallowCopy.sort(compareFn);

    return shallowCopy;
}

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    .filter(x => x % 2 == 0)
    .sorted((l, r) => r - l)
    .map(x => x * 2)

// -> [12, 8, 4]
```

Same in typescript:

```js
// extensions.ts
Array.prototype.sorted = function (compareFn?: ((a: any, b: any) => number) | undefined) {
    const shallowCopy = this.slice();
    shallowCopy.sort(compareFn);

    return shallowCopy;
}

declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        sorted(compareFn?: (a: T, b: T) => number): Array<T>;
    }
}

export {}

// index.ts
import 'extensions.ts';


[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    .filter(x => x % 2 == 0)
    .sorted((l, r) => r - l)
    .map(x => x * 2)

// -> [12, 8, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort a function without mutating the original, simply use `.map()` before sort to create a copy of the original array:

```js
const originalArr = [1, 45, 3, 21, 6];
const sortedArr = originalArr.map(value => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))).sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(sortedArr); // the logged output will be 1,3,6,21,45
```

The original array has not been modified, but you have a sorted version of it available to you. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` make sure it is a deep copy, not a shallow copy.