# How to sort by length and then alphabetically

Tags: javascript, sorting, string-length, alphabetical

Assume I had the following Javascript array. How do you sort by length, then alphabetically?

Assume the following array:

```
var array = ["a", "aaa", "bb", "bbb", "c"];
```

When sorted it should produce: `a, c, bb, aaa, bbb`.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 13):

You can first sort by length and then use `localeCompare()` to sort alphabetically.

```js
var array = ["a", "aaa", "bb", "bbb", "c"];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.length - b.length || a.localeCompare(b)
})

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Also works: `return a.length === b.length ? a.localeCompare(b) : a.length - b.length`

Answer (score 8):

Sort by length first then alphabetically using the || operator for more than one criteria. However, in your case, a simple sort will do.

```js
var array = ["a", "aaa", "bb", "bbb", "c"];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.length - b.length || a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(array);
```

Or

```js
var array =["c", "aa", "bb", "bbb", "b", "aaa", "a"].sort();

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.length - b.length || 0;
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Just a heads up about sort, it changes the source array so you don't need to assign it to a new variable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control

Comment: If you don't want to change the original array you can make a copy first like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592740/how-can-you-sort-an-array-without-mutating-the-original-array

Answer (score 0):

arr.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length || this)