# Sorting an array of objects by a certain string value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort an array of objects by a certain string value. For example, I have the below array of objects:

```
const stores = [
{id: 1, name: 'Store1', country: 'USA'},
{id: 2, name: 'Store2', country: 'Canada'},
{id: 3, name: 'Store3', country: 'USA'},
{id: 4, name: 'Store4', country: 'Canada'}
];
```

I would like to sort that array so all the objects with a country value of 'Canada' is first. I know you can sort by number, but I am not sure how to sort by a string value. How would I go about doing this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.toSorted()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted) with a custom sorting *(which compares two elements of the array and returns a negative number if the first element should come before the second, a positive number if the second element should come before the first, or zero if they are equal.)*
In our example:
The comparison function checks if the `country` value of the first object is *'Canada'* and the `country` value of the second object is not *'Canada'*, in which case it returns `-1` to indicate that the first object should come before the second. If the opposite is true, it returns `1`. If both objects have the same `country` value, it returns `0` to indicate that their order should not change.

```js
const stores = [ {id: 1, name: 'Store1', country: 'USA'}, {id: 2, name: 'Store2', country: 'Canada'}, {id: 3, name: 'Store3', country: 'USA'}, {id: 4, name: 'Store4', country: 'Canada'} ];
function sortByCountryFirst(array, country) {
  return array.toSorted((a, b) => {
    if (a.country === country && b.country !== country) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.country !== country && b.country === country) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
}
console.log(sortByCountryFirst(stores, 'Canada'));
```

Tip: Use [`.toSorted()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted) to sort an array without mutating the original array! [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76443700/14529779)

Comment: @navin1551 I am here to help you at any time :)