# JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)) vs [...array] for preventing an array to be mutated when using .sort()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

```
# version 1
let sortedGraphData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graphData))
    .sort((a, b) => { return a.playerStint > b.playerStint ? 1 : -1; });

# version 2
let sortedGraphData = [...graphData]
    .sort((a, b) => { return a.playerStint > b.playerStint ? 1 : -1; });

# version 3
let sortedGraphData = [...(graphData ?? [])]
    .sort((a, b) => { return a.playerStint > b.playerStint ? 1 : -1; });
```

The purpose for either `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` or `[...array]` is that I don't want the underlying `graphData` above to be mutated when sorting. `.sort()` seems to mutate the original array unlike `.map()`, `.filter()`

Our react app has a ton of version 1 code in our app. I am thinking it would be a good idea to convert these into version 2 (or 3 even better, because then `null` and `undefined` will fallback to an empty array, which we would prefer over an error being thrown. Per my quick research, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` creates a deep copy where `[...array]` creates a shallow copy of the array, and the latter is more performant and perhaps more common in react apps? Almost always I am using these before a `.sort()`.

Quick edit - seems like `.slice()` is an option, and that it would work similarly to `[...array]` which is to say it would make a shallow copy of the array?

Any recommendations? What is the best practice here?

**Context** - our app has been getting a strange `t.filter is not a function` errors on subsequent code `sortedGraphData.filter()...`, which would seem to indicates that `sortedGraphData` is not an array at times. Code snippet below:

```
// initialize, deep copy, sort
const graphData = someOtherArray || [];
const sortedGraphData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graphData))
    .sort((a, b) => { return a.playerStint > b.playerStint ? 1 : -1; });

// return early for bad array
if (!sortedGraphData || sortedGraphData.length === 0) { return; }

// filter
const finalData = sortedGraphData.filter(...)

ERROR: sortedGraphData.filter() is not a function (indicating that sortedGraphData is not an array).
```

We set a fallback value of `[]` to `graphData` when initializing it, and we also return early with the if statement, and yet we still get the `.filter() is not a function`. I am beginning to think the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` may be partly responsible, converting the array into a string or some other type? Perhaps the `if` statement would be better with an `Array.isArray()` check, but aside from that I am still confused how `sortedGraphData` is not an array triggering the error...

Comment: perhaps a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592740/how-can-you-sort-an-array-without-mutating-the-original-array, however the answers do not get into the weeds / the pros and cons of one approach vs the other? Both are recommended as solutions, with [...array] the most upvoted answer.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will serialize the data. Information in JavaScript objects would be destroyed in the process. Shallow copying with the spread operator or `slice` is the established solution. If you have the polyfill for it, you can use the new, non-mutative, sort method: `toSorted`. The interface is the same. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted

Comment: Thank you. `toSorted` will work just fine in all browsers? Frankly I don't know what `If you have the polyfill for it` means, I am not familiar with what polyfills are - I probably don't have it and will likely avoid this approach. But thank you again for info and recommendation.

Comment: Browser compatibility should be considered low, which is why you want a polyfill. You can read more about polyfills here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill

Comment: @Andrew's comment should be posted as an answer to be accepted.

Comment: You can make a `structuredClone`, is what a comment has pointed our on Stack Overflow a while back, which is the btter way to make deep clones. `window.stru cturedClone`. It's so useful, I feel I need to point it out here because I didn't know either and it's a godsend. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` will serialize the data. Information in JavaScript objects would be destroyed in the process. Shallow copying with the spread operator or `slice` is the established solution. If you have the polyfill for it, you can use the new, non-mutative, sort method: `toSorted`. The interface is the same.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted

Browser compatibility should be considered low, which is why you want a polyfill. You can read more about polyfills here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill